# Get records in batches from MongoDB using golang

Tags: mongodb, go, batch-processing, mgo

How can one fetch records in batches from a mongo database using golang?  I know mongoDB itself has something called cursor.batchSize(), but im trying to find an example using a golang driver.  From what I've seen the golang library mgo has a function called Batch, but Im trying to figure out how to us it.

Ideally I'm looking for something like this:

```
const cursor = useDb.collection(mycollection).find().batchSize(10000);
for (let doc = await cursor.next(); doc != null; doc = await cursor.next()) {
    if (doc._id % divisor === 0) {
        counter++;
    }
}
```

I have something like this so far:

```
err := c.Find(nil).Batch(1).All(&items)
```

But it's not working like expected.

Links:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.batchSize/
https://godoc.org/github.com/globalsign/mgo#Query.Batch

Comment: Hi, were you able to implement this? Highly appreciate if you can post your code. Thanks

Comment: I did, but I don't have access to the changes anymore

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `batchSize()` specifies the number of documents to return in each batch of the response.  You will still all results.  For example, if the total number of returned docs is 100 and you specify batch size as 20, you will have 1 `find` and 4 `getMore` commands sent from the client to the `mongod` to complete the request.

One little trick you can use to verify.  Use `db.setProfilingLevel(0, 0)` from mongo shell to log everything in the log file.  Execute your test app and you will see `find` and `getMore` recorded in the log.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation.  I was trying to figure out how not to load millions of records at once into the app for batch processing.  I supposed I can something with limit.  Thanks.