# How to increase batch size in the official MongoDB Golang driver?

Tags: mongodb, go

Is there possible to increase the batch size for operations using MongoDB Official Golang Driver?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54117568/get-records-in-batches-from-mongodb-using-golang

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but it's not the ask I did. I would like to know where and how to set the batch size param in the MongoDB Golang driver.

Comment: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/blob/master/x/mongo/driver/batch_cursor.go#L149

See this code

Answer (score 0):

Set batch size for a specific query, using MongoDB Golang driver:

```
opt := options.Find().SetBatchSize(batchSize)
curr, err = Db.client.Database(dbName).Collection(USERS).Find(ctx, filter, opt)
```

Update the batch size is essential in some situations to improve query performance